# OpenSSL Encryption in Debug and Release

Tags: c++, visual-studio, encryption, openssl, cryptography

I have the following code (modified `ik` and `iv`, of course):

```
#include "openssl/evp.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::ostringstream;

void Encryption(bool encrypt, const string &in, string &out)
{
    int ik[17] = {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
    int iv[17] = { 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32 };
    ik[16] = iv[16] = '\0';
    unsigned char ckey[17], ivec[17];
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        ckey[i] = ik[i];
        ivec[i] = iv[i];
    }
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_CipherInit(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), ckey, ivec, encrypt);
    unsigned blocksize = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_block_size(ctx);

    int out_len;
    int n = in.length() + blocksize;
    unsigned char *cipher_buf = new unsigned char[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cipher_buf[i] = ' ';
    EVP_CipherUpdate(ctx, cipher_buf, &out_len,
                     (const unsigned char*)in.c_str(), in.length());
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss.write((char*)cipher_buf, out_len);
    EVP_CipherFinal(ctx, cipher_buf, &out_len);
    ss.write((char*)cipher_buf, out_len);
    delete cipher_buf;
    out = ss.str();
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
}    

int main()
{
    string out;
    string in = "TEST";
    string back;
    Encryption(true, in, out);
    cout << "---------------" << endl;
    Encryption(false, out, back);
    cout << "TEST > " << out << " > " << back << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, this code encrypts a string, decrypts it and then prints out the result from both steps.

If I run this code in Debug, it works just fine, outputting `TEST > *gibberish A* > TEST`. If I run it on Release, however, it fails, printing only `TEST > *gibberish B (not A)* >`, because `back` remains empty. Seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998684/aes-encryption-problem-in-debug-and-release-mode) and another one I can't find now, I made a copy of my Release configuration and went changing one parameter at a time to the equivalent value in the Debug configuration. When I changed `Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Basic Runtime Checks` from `Default` to `Both (/RTC1, equiv. to /RTCsu) (/RTC1)`, this new Release configuration worked, printing exactly the same values as in the Debug configuration. Obviously, by then I'd already changed many other parameters, but it was only when I changed the value of `/RTC` that any change was clear in the execution.

I also noticed something else. If I removed the `cout << "---------------" << endl;` line in `main()`, the default Release configuration also works, printing `TEST > *gibberish C* > TEST`. The encryption gibberish is different to both the Debug result and the Release with the `cout` line. Also, if I place that `cout` call anywhere other than between my `Encryption` calls, it works.

So I have two questions I believe may be interrelated:

- Why does the value of `/RTC` affect the encryption result? Given that `/RTC` should be disabled in Release builds, is it possible to generate equivalent encrypted data (aka gibberish) in both Debug and Release, so as to make them interchangeable, without losing `/RTC` in Debug?

  - Why does the use of `cout` in between my `Encryption()` calls modify the result in Release mode and only in Release mode?

And, should it be worth mentioning, everything is built with the static runtime library (`/MT[d]`).

Comment: Not the source of your problem, but; your code could benefit a great deal from using modern C++ - things like `auto`, smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr` & `std::shared_ptr`) and range-for. Instead of manually typing types all over the place and managing memory by hand, etc. Just a tip :)

Comment: I would start with a Know Answer Test (KAT), likes [this one](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/aes/AESAVS.pdf) from NIST.  See section 6.2.  That will allow you to tell which answer is correct.  I *suspect* you have memory overwriting issues, and the checks are causing different bits of memory to get clobbered.  Step through the broken version (probably Release), and work out where the problem lies.  (You do know you can run Release code under the debugger?)

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks for the tips. I actually do use such techniques (all hail range-for) in my main code. In regards to `auto` I actually changed my code to post it here to make it more explicit. And yeah, I could have used smart pointers for cipher_buf, I suppose. But how could I have used a range-for to populate cipher_buf, without an iterator? That's one trick I'd love to learn.

Comment: You program has problems beyond debug and release. AES has a forward and reverse direction. You should be using `EVP_EncryptInit`, `EVP_EncryptUpdate` and `EVP_EncryptFinal` for encryption; and `EVP_DecryptInit`, `EVP_DecryptUpdate` and `EVP_DecryptFinal` for decryption. Also see [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: @jww I'll take a look at those. I based my code on what I found on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24856303/2175231), which only uses Encrypt.

Comment: @Wasabi - The question you cited uses `EVP_EncryptInit`, `EVP_EncryptUpdate` and `EVP_EncryptFinal` for encryption; and `EVP_DecryptInit`, `EVP_DecryptUpdate` and `EVP_DecryptFinal` for decryption. In any case, do what the OpenSSL team tells you to do.